# multiple api call of same api using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I have list of albums I want to make an api call for each item and retrieve result in new List Object.

I have function which returns LiveData<List>

```
fun getAlbumsfromRoom(userId: Int): LiveData<List<Album>>
```

now I want to get images for each album from retrofit api

```
fun getPhoto(albumId: Int): LiveData<Photo>
```

How can I get List of photos at once for all the albums ? because I want to attach these photos to gridview adapter, I am new to kotlin and coroutines, I have tred calling it from inside a for loop, but it's not working.
in ViewModel

```
 fun getPhotoAlbum(albums: List<Album>): LiveData<List<PhotoAlbum>> {
  val resultLivedata: MutableLiveData<List<PhotoAlbum>> = MutableLiveData()
  val result = arrayListof<PhotoAlbum>() 
    for(album in albums) {
        photo = repository.getPhoto(album.id)
        result.add(PhotoAlbum(album.id, album.userId, photo.url))
 }
   resultLiveData.value = result
return resultLiveData
 }


 data class Album(val AlbumId: Int,
             val userId: Int,
             val title: String)


class Photo (val id: Int,
       val albumId: Int,
        val title: String,
        val url: String,
        val thumbnailUrl: String)
```

PhotoAlbum class is something I have added so I can combine both classes

```
class PhotoAlbum(val albumId: Int,
val photoId:Int,
val url: String,
val thumbnailUrl: String)
```

get Albums response

```
[
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 8,
    "title": "That is great"
}, 
{...} 
]
```

Get Photo response

```
 [
{
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 8,
    "title": "Photo 1",
    "url": "https://somethingurl",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://somethumbnailurl"
}
]
```

I was thinking of using observe getPhotoAlbum inside my activity and pass the result to an Adapter, but it's not working, I know maybe I am doing it wrongly.
so where should I make changes to achieve the desired result in viewModel ? or repository where I have my retrofit call ? is there any operator I can use to solve this problem? is it possible to solve using coroutine flow? Please let me know if anyone needs more details or any other explanation

Comment: send a sample of your json response let's start from there

Comment: do well to send your model too

Comment: there is only one image url , please explain what you want

Comment: there can multiple photos for one albumId I want image url and thumbnailUrl from first photo. basically I want to display all albums from user into gridview but that gridview item background display image of first photo of that album. similarly I want to do same for all albums. let's assume user has 10 albums for all the albums I want to get thumbnailUrl and ImageUrl and bind it to gridview during UserDetails screen load. ImageUrl I will use for onClick event of Any Album from that gridview.

Comment: @ebs237 I have added what I want to achieve